# My application is close when call another application in my application

Tags: android

I try to call another application within my application to share data. But when the other application opens, suddenly my application is crashes without any errors or warning. How can I fix this case?

my code is

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
boolean facebookAppFound = false;
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
    for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
        if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp)  || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase() .contains(nameApp)) {
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My Info");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath))); 
            share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            facebookAppFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!facebookAppFound) {
        String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/mypage/mypage.php?u=" + Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath));
        share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
    }
} 
else {
    if (!facebookAppFound) {
        String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/shwetech/shwetech.php?u=" + Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath));
        share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
    } 
}
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select")); 

.....
```

After finish this code `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));`  my application is close.

Comment: Show us your code. And explain in detail

Comment: share some code or check u r calling finish or not when you are opening another application...

Comment: logcat output or some sort of debug output will be helpful.

Comment: @Veeru , logcat has no warnings,no errors